Combining Output Formats in R Markdown
Is there a way to combine functions from the both bookdown and officedown in the Word output, and not just from the first one written in the .Rmd file?
When I write this code:
---
title: "Analysis"

output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: "reference.docx"
  bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: "reference.docx"  
bibliography: references.bib
---


{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = TRUE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    out.width = NULL,
  out.height = NULL
)



# Header1

## Header2

### Header3

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum

<br>

Lorem Ipsum:

-   Lorem Ipsum (Image: \@ref(fig:img1))

<br>





{r img1, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height =2, fig.cap="Image 1", fig.id = "img1", fig.cap.style = "Image Caption"}
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(officer)   
library(flextable)
library(officedown)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(jpeg)

img <- readJPEG("rmarkdown_logo.jpg")

grid.raster(img)




<br>

#### Lorem Ipsum

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->


{r w_height, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, tab.cap="women height", tab.id = "rezultatiCM816", tab.cap.style = "Table Caption"}
height <- women$height
height


<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->


it ignores bookdown (it doesn't do automatic numeration of the chapters and it doesn't do me cross-referencing), but it makes me a landscape page from the officedown, but when I write this code:
---
title: "Analysis"

output: 
  bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: "reference.docx" 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: "reference.docx" 
bibliography: references.bib
---


{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = TRUE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    out.width = NULL,
  out.height = NULL
)



# Header1

## Header2

### Header3

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum

<br>

Lorem Ipsum:

-   Lorem Ipsum (Image: \@ref(fig:img1))

<br>




{r img1, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height =2, fig.cap="Image 1", fig.id = "img1", fig.cap.style = "Image Caption"}
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(officer)   
library(flextable)
library(officedown)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(jpeg)

img <- readJPEG("rmarkdown_logo.jpg")

grid.raster(img)



<br>

#### Lorem Ipsum

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->


{r w_height, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, tab.cap="women height", tab.id = "rezultatiCM816", tab.cap.style = "Table Caption"}
height <- women$height
height


<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->

it ignores officedown (it doesn't show me a landscape page), but it puts an automatic numeration for the chapters and cross-refferencing.
So, it takes only what is first written. Is there a way to combine these two, so there can be both shown an automatic numeration of the chapters and cross-refferencing from bookdown and a landscape page from officedown?

it is not possible because what you indicate in output are the engines that compile your doc and by definition only one engine can. You need to find a workaround to implement the functions you are missing in one format. For instance, how to do landscape in bookdown
